# Concatenar texto dentro de un label Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Necesito ayuda para concatenar dentro de un label dos parámetros en el texto, Estos parámetros los obtengo desde un datasource  en asp.net y los despliego directamente.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<asp:Label ID="Nro_orden_despachoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Nro_orden_despacho")+Eval("Origen")) %>' />
```

Existe alguna manera.
Les agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Has probado sin el `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`?

Comment: Es que trigo datos de una grid y ese system.web me ayuda a traer directamente ese campo

Comment: cual es el origen de datos del gridview ? es un datatable o una List que defines con una class que defines

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos formas de lograr lo que buscas

Podrias usar

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NombreHeader">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Nro_orden_despachoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Nro_orden_despacho")+ " " + Eval("Origen")%>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

O tambien resolverlo desde los datos, por ejemplo si tu origen es una `List<>` en base a un `class` que defines podrias agregar una propiedad adicional que una

```
public class ClassNombre{ 

   public string Nro_orden_despacho {get;set;}
   public string Origen {get;set;}

   public DespechoOrigen 
   {
     get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Nro_orden_despacho, this.Origen ); }
   }

}
```

entonces en el grid puedes usar esta propiedad de solo lectura en la columna